# "body > div" What is this syntax?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm looking through some style sheets and I am seeing syntax that I have not seen before:

```
body > div {
```

OR

```
body > div > div {
```

Is this just another method for descendant selection? If not, then what is this doing?

Comment: It's the child selector. Look here for example: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is called the direct descendant or child selector. Which is used to select direct children of a parent.

> The element>element selector is used to select elements with a specific parent.

To illustrate, check out this example

```css
div#first > p {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <p>This paragraph will be selected</p>
  <div>
    <p>This paragraph will not be selected</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

On the other hand the descendant selector, selects ALL descendants, not just direct children.

Here is an example.

```css
#first p {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="first">
  <p>This paragraph will be selected</p>
  <div>
    <p>This paragraph is also a descendant. It will be selected. </p>
  </div>
</div>
```